# Where do I ask Controversial Questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was wondering if I can ask what the *best program/language to run a (**EDIT: Home**) server*, but knowing all of the questions tagged too vague/controversial, I'm wondering if chat is the way to go.

If I can't use chat, what is the best place to ask controversial questions (if any)?

Comment: Even in chat, people wouldn't be able to give you a serious answer with such a vague question.

Comment: I hear [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-server-side-programming-languages-or-technologies-for-large-databases) is pretty great for this sorta thing. YMMV.

Comment: @Shog9 great thing about Quora is that they are unlikely to [complain about using them as a toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773)

Comment: If there was a clear "best", there wouldn't be dozens of alternatives being maintained that you have trouble choosing from. You can't run away from the responsibility to do personal investigation by asking for "the best". It doesn't exist. Try searching for one that matches your needs, and then all of a sudden you have to be very specific about what your needs are.

Comment: Since I know what is best, and everyone else in the world is wrong, I'll give you your answer so you can move on to development.  Code it in this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck.  Go.  Do it.  You asked, you have your answer, now show me some results.

Comment: @Will So I should ask controversial questions on a wikipedia page. Right.

Comment: Oh, you can't reading comprehension. I'm sorry. You'll have to hire a developer in that case. Please don't respond to this comment asking me why I think elephants are living under the kitchen table.

Comment: @Will I thought that elephants are under the coffee tables... my life is ruined now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowhere. Stack Exchange Q&A network knows that it can't cater each and every question in the universe, so you may need to find another place for them.

On another note, I doubt anyone could ever answer that question as it is, even if you find a place dedicated to answer those kind of questions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use Quora!